# Logistic regression, after adding covariate interaction term, the key IV becomes insignificant (R studio)

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm trying to understand why adding a covariate and an interaction term gives different results on the significance of the key IV from adding only the covariate. I have a categorical IV (2 levels), and a binary outcome (coded as 1 and 0). I also have a continuous covariate.

If I only add IV (i.e., condition) to the logistic regression model, the IV has a significant effect on DV:

```
glm(formula = DV ~ condition, family = "binomial", data = df)

(AIC: 307.38)
```

[image]

If I add IV and the covariate to the logistic regression model, the IV still significant:

```
glm(formula = DV ~ condition + covariate, family = "binomial", data = df)

(AIC: 306.29)
```

[image]

But when I added IV, covariate and the interaction, the IV no longer significant but the covariate became significant:

```
glm(formula = DV ~ condition * covariate, family = "binomial", data = df)

(AIC: 306.48)
```

[image]

I'm so confused. It's there any problem to add interaction to logistic regression, or it's the fact that my IV doesn't really have an effect on DV? I read a similar post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113428/covariate-no-longer-significant-after-inclusion-of-interaction-term) but I'm still confused.

Follow-up:
I tried to only include covariate in the model:

```
glm(formula = DV ~ covariate, family = "binomial", data = df)

(AIC: 308.69, not sure if this is relevant)
```

[image]

Comment: Vote to move to https://stats.stackexchange.com as it needs stats advice rather than programming. Can you edit your question with the results of `glm(formula = DV ~ condition * I(covariate-mean(covariate, na.rm=TRUE)), family = "binomial", data = df)` please.

Comment: Second @user20650's comments and votes.  In general, it's **strongly** recommended to use text formats (cut-and-paste to a code block) rather than images to present information about outputs ... easier to search, more accessible to screen readers, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the coefficients in your function 'soak up' a certain amount of predictiveness. If you have a variable whose coefficient decreases after including a new variable, specifically an interaction term, then that term is replacing a certain amount of the original variables predictive power.

This does not mean that your original variable is not significant because it certainly was when the new variable was not present. This does mean that the two variables are competing against each other. I suggest you evaluate the model by replacing the old variable with the new variable then decide which makes better sense to keep.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've updated my question with more information. If the model only has the covariate, the estimate (maybe this is what you referred to as the coefficient?) is smaller (in its absolute term) than that of the IV when only IV is in the model. Does this suggest that in terms of predictive power, IV is better than the covariate because it explained more of the changes in DV?

Comment: IV has more influence on the result than the covariate. It is better? To answer that I would think about whether IV makes more sense in terms of what it represents in the real world than the covariate regardless of the estimate. If you can't understand or explain why IV is important then I would be vary cautious of including it. Only you can know that but if both make sense to you, then its probably safe to go with the higher estimate. If you see strange things happening to your estimates if you continue adding new variables, then this might be a sign to go back and switch out IV.